# FullCalendar not showing Events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, fullcalendar

I want to bind the fullcalendar by arshaw into my MVC 3 Application and save the events into a SQL Server database which is in my App_Data Folder.
But I have a few problems. On the View of my Action the calendar is not rendered but I see the JSON result from my controller.
I looked in every thread on stackoverflow dealing with this problem and none of them helped me.

Here is the code:

#### Database

```
Name    Datatype        AllowNullValues
id      int             False   
title   varchar(MAX)    False   
start   varchar(MAX)    False   
end     varchar(MAX)    True    
allday  bit             True
```

#### Auto generated Calendar Model by ADO.NET

```
namespace MvcApplication5.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Calendar
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> allday { get; set; }
}
}
```

#### HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult GetEvents()
    {
        IList<Calendar> taskList = new List<Calendar>();

        taskList.Add(new Calendar
        {
            id = 1,
            title = "Google Search",
            start = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            allday = false
        });
        taskList.Add(new Calendar
        {
            id = 2,
            title = "Bing Search",
            start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
            allday = false
        });

        return Json(taskList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

#### GetEvents.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>GetEvents</title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar-1.6.1/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar-1.6.1/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar-1.6.1/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar-1.6.1/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js")"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar-1.6.1/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                editable: true,
                eventSources: '/Home/GetEvents'
            });

        });
   </script>
    <style>

    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        }

    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

</style>
    <div id ="calendar">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this what I get in my View

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Google Search","start":"06-18-2013","end":"06-19-2013","allday":false},{"id":2,"title":"Bing Search","start":"06-20-2013","end":"06-21-2013","allday":false}]
```

When I return View() the calendar is correctly rendered. Can someone please help me?
This makes me losing my nerves! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your calendar setup is incorrect. The easiest change would be to change eventSources to [events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)

```
events: '/Home/GetEvents'
```

Otherwise (if you would like to use [eventSources](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/)) you need to setup like this

```
eventSources: [{
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    color: 'yellow',   // an option!
    textColor: 'black' // an option!
}}
```

Edit:
To help debugging try the success and error callbacks:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

events: {
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(a, b, c) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(a, b, c) {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Also, not sure if you already know this, but you don't need to include both the min file and the normal file (the fullcalendar.js file), they  contain the same code. The min file is generally used in production while the normal file is used in debugging

Comment: Your solutions do not work either @tocallaghan. I still get the JSON feed and no calendar is rendered

Comment: Strange, that seems to be the only thing obviously wrong. Where are you capturing the event data that you included? It's it from the debug tools of your browser?

Comment: That is totally strange. I am trying to solve this problem for now 4 days! The event data is shown in the browser when I call type the url of my action:

http://localhost:20885/Home/GetEvents

Comment: Ok, so it seems that your data is correct and your calendar is setup correctly. Have you tried debugging the javascript to verify it's being called? I added some code to let you put breakpoints to see what's happening after you call your action

Comment: I just noticed your page (GetEvents.cshtml) and your ajax call (GetEvents()) have the same name. This could be the issue. You probably need one action for the cshtml page and a separate one for the ajax call

Comment: I moved the code from the GetEvent.cshtml into Calender.cshtml. 
The calendar is correctly rendered but the events are not shown. I set the breakpoint on the GetEvents Actionmethod. The methods get called when I enter the calendar through the correct url. The problem is, that the method doesn't pass the events to the Calendar View.

Comment: BTW I added the code snippet you suggested and it tells that there was error while fetching events

Comment: You need to debug the javascript. That error is just the alert you hardcoded. To debug (assuming Chrome but should be similar for others) press f12, go to sources tab and click the run symbol on the left, select your file (should be called Calendar if you javascript is inline) and put a breakpoint in the error function. Refresh your page and when the breakpoint is hit have look at the parameters (a, b, and c - I can't remember which one), this should give you more information. But it looks like your network path is incorrect, replace '/Home/Calendar' with exactly what you put in the url bar